# How to play songs without refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I want to play the songs only if the user press the button 'play',

without Waiting to load all the 21 songs.

when I press the button 'play' the page jump up like refreshing ,it is not normal.

what I can do to improve my code.

please try to play the songs in the [example site](http://www.rafih.co.il/) and see the problem.

many thanks.

```
var Music = {


        init:function(){

                        song = new Audio();
                        //speaKer = document.getElementById("imgSpeaker");
                        this.volume = 0.08;
                        this.isMute = false;
                        canPlayMP3 = (typeof song.canPlayType === "function" && song.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") !== "");
                        song.src = canPlayMP3 ? "http://rafih.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/1.mp3" : "http://rafih.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/1.ogg";
                        song.preload = 'auto';
        },

    /*  start:function(){
                        song.src = canPlayMP3 ? "http://rafih.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/1.mp3" : "http://rafih.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/1.ogg";
                        song.volume = 0.08;
                        song.autoplay = true;
                        song.load();
        },*/

         play: function () {
                        song.volume = 0.08;
                        song.autoplay = true;
                        song.load();
                       // Music.speaker();

                    },

        stop: function () {
                        if (!song.ended) {
                            song.pause();
                        }   
                    },

        next: function () {
                        if (curr < count) {
                            curr++;
                        }else curr = 1;
                        song.src = canPlayMP3 ? "http://rafih.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/" + curr + ".mp3" : "http://rafih.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/" + curr + ".ogg";


        },          


      };
      function load() {
        Music.init();

      }
```

Comment: you might want to consider using jPlayer for html5 audio. it has some nice built in features. i'm not sure if you can attach an event when a file finishes playing to play the next file. jPlayer will allow you to attach an event to when a file stops playing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return false from the play buttons event handler, to prevent the page from scrolling to the top.

Change:

```
<div id="play" onclick='Music.play()'>
```

To:

```
<div id="play" onclick='Music.play(); return false;'>
```

Comment: You could also simply `return false` from inside the `play()` method. That way you don't have to modify the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `anchor` in your link, such as `href="#"`. A very simple fix would be to add `return false;` in to your inline handler attribute, such as `onclick="Music.play(); return false;"`, however that isin't a good approach and is considered a bad practice.

Instead you could add your handlers programmatically, it will also make your code more modular and testable:

```
var Music = {
    init: function (options) {
        var playBtn = this.playBtn = document.querySelector(options.playBtn);

        playBtn.addEventListener('click', this._onPlayBtnClick.bind(this));
        //...

        return this;
    },
    _onPlayBtnClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents the browser's default behaviour
        this.play();
    },
    //...
};
```

Then you could do something like:

```
function load() {
    var musicController = Object.create(Music).init({
        playBtn: '#play',
        //...
    });
}
```

You could also use it as a singleton like:

```
Music.init({ ... });
```